# Como Usar ToolStripDropDownButton no vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Não acho a ToolStripDropDownButton na Toolbox no meu VS.

Comment: é Windows Forms ?

Comment: Sim...E uso o VS Community 2015

Comment: Eu também uso VS Community 2015.

Answer (score 4):

O nome do componente é [ToolStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*e rodando:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]